# MediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds() returns NaN when called in Initialize method

Tags: java, javafx, slider, media-player, duration

I am working on MediaPlayer using JavaFX to finish javaFX course. I am trying to set file total duration to the slider max property. Then I want to add Listener to the currentTimeProperty so the slider is tracking the timeline.

I wrote a code that works perfectly fine:

```
timeSlider.setMax(mediaPlayerMain.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
System.out.println("Max value: " + mediaPlayerMain.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
mediaPlayerMain.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue o, Object oldVal, Object newVal) {
        timeSlider.setValue(mediaPlayerMain.getCurrentTime().toSeconds());
    }
    
});
```

It works when I call it once the video is already playing. The problem is that I want to call it once the MediaView is ready so the slider works automatically from the beginning. If I put it in the initialize method the `mediaPlayerMain.getTotalDuration().toSeconds()` returns NaN so the period has to be UNKNOWN according to the Duration API.

How to wait for the mediaPlayer object to be ready so the slider is working?
Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just register a listener with the media player's status, and set the slider's max value when it changes to `READY`? That has to happen before the current time changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't something like

```
@FXML
private Slider timeSlider ;

@FXML
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayerMain ;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    if (mediaPlayerMain.getStatus() == MediaPlayer.Status.UNKNOWN) {
        mediaPlayerMain.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> {
            if (newStatus == MediaPlayer.Status.READY) {
                initializeSlider();
            } 
        });
    } else {
        initializeSlider();
    }
}

private void initializeSlider() {
    timeSlider.setMax(mediaPlayerMain.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
    mediaPlayerMain.currentTimeProperty().addListener((obs, oldTime, newTime) -> 
        timeSlider.setValue(newTime.toSeconds()));
}
```

work?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Although I've seen it in Javascript and Java, I have never used '->'. If someone finds it new too, there is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to the api of the expression.

Comment: @KubaWoźny Lambda Expressions have been part of Java since 2014...

Comment: I am actually just starting to learn programming, that's why, nevertheless thank you for help!